# Rights as joint tenant paying mortgage

Tags: united-states, mortgage, california, jointly-held-property

In California, my husband and I bought a home in which we are still paying the mortgage.  His family (mom, dad and sister) are not paying anything on the mortgage but all 5 names are on the deed.  If my husband and I want to sell the home, what are our rights to what percentage?

Comment: How are the names listed on the deed? Examples include "tenants in common", "joint tenants with rights of survivorship", and "tenants by entirity".

Comment: Do you have a written document that spells out the partnership percentages and rights?

Comment: You may be able to find the deed information on your county's property tax website.

Comment: @mkennedy, to comply with a law about revealing the home addresses of public officials, my California county has removed that information from their website. It's still possible to get by physically visiting the county offices.

Comment: @ThePhoton My county lists owners (maybe they're omitted if public officials) which is why I said "may be able."